# maxLik in R used with doParallel an foreach for faster implementation

Tags: r, performance, foreach, doparallel

I need to make an MLE estimation for a dataset of 31000 observations, with log-likelihood function self-coded. There are 21 parameters to estimate for the dataset. In order to do the estimation, I am using maxLik package with newton-raphson method in R. Hessian and gradients of the log-likelihood function is not given to the function itself. Here is how the data reading and how log-likelihood function is calculated.

[Edit @Patric, use random data]

```
nObs <- 30000
nVeh   <- runif(nObs, 1, 2)
adult1 <- runif(nObs, 0, 1)
adult2 <- runif(nObs, 0, 1)
adult3 <- runif(nObs, 0, 1)
adult4 <- runif(nObs, 0, 1)

params <- runif(21, 1, 4)

## Matrix to keep loglikelihood records for each observation
LL <- matrix (0, ncol=1, nrow=nObs)
logLik <- function(params){
for (i in 1:nObs){
            V0 <- params[1]  
            V1 <- params[2] + params[6] * adult1[i] + params[10] * adult2[i] + params[14] * adult3[i] + params[18] * adult4[i]
            V2 <- params[3] + params[7] * adult1[i] + params[11] * adult2[i] + params[15] * adult3[i] + params[19] * adult4[i]
            V3 <- params[4] + params[8] * adult1[i] + params[12] * adult2[i] + params[16] * adult3[i] + params[20] * adult4[i]
            V4 <- params[5] + params[9] * adult1[i] + params[13] * adult2[i] + params[17] * adult3[i] + params[21] * adult4[i]

            vU <- matrix (c(V0, V1, V2, V3, V4), nrow = 1, ncol = 5)

            pChosen <- exp(vU[min(nVeh[i] + 1,5)]) / sum(exp(vU))
            LL[i] <- log(pChosen)
    }
    return(sum(LL))
}

system.time(logLik(params))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.7     0.0     0.7
```

The above code runs very slowly. The MLE estimation takes days. Therefore, I sampled the data according to stratified random sampling and reduced it from 31000 observations to 5000 observations.

Yet, it still runs slowly. Therefore, I decided to use doParallel and foreach libraries' backend functions to parallelize for loop inside log-likelihood function. Here is what I added and changed for loop:

```
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
..... some code here to read data ......
logLik <- function(params){
    foreach (i=1:(nObs), .combine = "cbind") %do% {
       ...some more code content of log likelihood written above ...
    }
return(sum(LL))
}
```

I am not familiar with parallel computing and I read a lot about and tried to implement what I learnt in smaller function examples. Above structure works in the same code with only five parameters assuming V0, V1, V2, V3, and V4 are all defined with constants. It is relatively fast around 5 minutes. Yet, when I run the above model with 21 parameters to estimate in sampled data of 5000 observations, it is again painfully slow.

Is there any other way to get maxLik function run faster? Any clue or hint, also any reading material towards faster run-time is appreciated. I checked the website with search keys "maxLik", "parallel in R" etc. yet I could not find a suggestion or question.

PS: The question might be marked negatively due to no sample data however due to confidentiality, I cannot provide a sample data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some quick speed ups would be to (1) vectorize it, and (2) save some calculations by basic math eg- log(exp(a) / b) = log(exp(a)) - log(b) = a - log(b)

Comment: Other than than, I'd suggest writing it in C/C++. It doesn't seem a particularly difficult C/C++ function

Comment: Hello @Alex Thanks for your suggestions. As per the first suggestion, it was originally in vectors. I compared both models with constant parameters (5 parameters) and first model (11 parameters). I timed the elapsed time with proc.time () function and there was no reduction between two, both in regular and parallelized code.

Comment: @Alex For the second, do you suggest using Rcpp implementation? I thought about that too and was reading a lot about R and C++ integration. However, I am not quite familiar how I can achieve this. If you suggest I should go this path, I will deepen my reading and find some Rcpp tutorials to try to implement. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kukushkin I am trying to generate some random data and reproduce your case with "nObs = 30000", and this piece of code is really fast with only 0.7 second. I will edit your question and could you take a look if I generate the correct data?

Comment: @Patric I really appreciate your help. I know due to lack of data, I become a burden for you. However, I will check the data out once you prepare. Thanks a lot. Also, I will put an update with vectorized code and how summary() function of maxLik gives a problem.

Comment: @Patric Thanks again. The data generation is correct.

Comment: `multinomial logit`?

Comment: @Khashaa yes it is, if you are going to suggest mlogit package, i am not interested in it, as i am supposed to customize with different types of models.

Comment: Maybe too late but anyway...  As I understand, one loglik calculation takes 0.7 seconds.  'days' for this calculations is by far too much, and I guess the problem is convergence, not maxLik.  In a way, your model and your data do not match.  Another unexplored source of speed-up is providing analytic gradients (and Hessian).  In case you have numeric problems, this may inhibit convergence.